# How can I remove the legend title in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have a question concerning the legend in ggplot2.

Say I have a hypothetical dataset about mean carrot length for two different colours at two farms:

```
carrots<-NULL
carrots$Farm<-rep(c("X","Y"),2)
carrots$Type<-rep(c("Orange","Purple"),each=2)
carrots$MeanLength<-c(10,6,4,2)
carrots<-data.frame(carrots)
```

I make a simple bar plot:

```
require(ggplot2)
p<-ggplot(carrots,aes(y=MeanLength,x=Farm,fill=Type)) + 
geom_bar(position="dodge") +
opts(legend.position="top")
p
```

My question is: is there a way to remove the title ('Type') from the legend?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [remove legend title in ggplot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771546/remove-legend-title-in-ggplot)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can modify the legend title by passing it as the first parameter to a scale.  For example:

```
ggplot(carrots, aes(y=MeanLength, x=Farm, fill=Type)) + 
  geom_bar(position="dodge") +
  theme(legend.position="top", legend.direction="horizontal") +
  scale_fill_discrete("")
```

There is also a shortcut for this, i.e. `labs(fill="")`

Since your legend is at the top of the chart, you may also wish to modify the legend orientation.  You can do this using `opts(legend.direction="horizontal")`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Andrie, that worked perfectly. It's interesting you mentioned legend.direction="horizontal". I wanted to do this, but it didn't work in the old R version I have been using on my old laptop (R 2.11.1, shame on me) but the feature seems to be working in R 2.13.1!

Comment: using `NULL` instead of `""` doesn't attempt to draw the title at all, otherwise there's a bit too much space where the title would be when the legend box is visible

Answer (score 59):

I found that the best option is to use `+ theme(legend.title = element_blank())` as user "gkcn" noted.

For me (on 03/26/15) using the previously suggested `labs(fill="")` and `scale_fill_discrete("")` remove one title, only to add in another legend, which is not useful.

Comment: the best answer, because name = "" just put a white space and scale_manual is more a general answer

Comment: This worked for me. The other ones didn't because they added an additional legend.

Answer (score 29):

You can use `labs`:

```
p + labs(fill="")
```

[image: plot example]

Comment: There will be white space where the title used to be, use the answer by Yuriy if you don't want white space.

Answer (score 25):

The only way worked for me was using `legend.title = theme_blank()` and I think it is the most convenient variant in comparison to `labs(fill="")` and `scale_fill_discrete("")`, which also could be useful in some cases.

```
ggplot(carrots,aes(y=MeanLength,x=Farm,fill=Type)) + 
geom_bar(position="dodge") +
opts(
    legend.position="top",
    legend.direction="horizontal",
    legend.title = theme_blank()
)
```

P.S. There are more useful options in [documentation](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Legend-Attributes).

Comment: opts() and theme_blank are obsolete now. Use: "+ theme(legend.title = element_blank())" instead.

Comment: Using legend.title = element.blank() over the options which set an empty string is that there is no extra white space above the legend where the legend title used to be.

Answer (score 7):

You've got two good options already, so here's another using `scale_fill_manual()`. Note this also lets you specify the colors of the bars easily:

```
ggplot(carrots,aes(y=MeanLength,x=Farm,fill=Type)) + 
  geom_bar(position="dodge") +
  opts(legend.position="top") +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "", values = c("Orange" = "orange", "Purple" = "purple"))
```

If you are using the up-to-date (As of January 2015) version of ggplot2 (version 1.0), then the following should work:

```
ggplot(carrots, aes(y = MeanLength, x = Farm, fill = Type)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  theme(legend.position="top") +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "", values = c("Orange" = "orange", "Purple" = "purple"))
```

Comment: Thanks, @Chase. Not only did it work but it's also the most beautiful colour scheme I have ever seen :)

Comment: +1: This is an important option because when using multiple scales (e.g. `scale_fill_manual`, `scale_color_manual`, `scale_shape_manual`), they need the same `name` or multiple legends will appear.

Comment: @Chase, will this replace the title with an empty string of some non-zero height, thereby creating a vertical space at the top of the legend box (when there is one) or will it behave like ``theme(legend.title = element_blank())`` and gobble the line? On my non-mwe it looks like there's extra space, but could be something else going on.

Comment: @PatrickT - good question. This answer is pretty much 100% out of date at this point...`opts` hasn't been used since `0.9.1`, the scales package is now separated out from `ggplot2`, etc. etc. I'll go back and update this when I get a chance, but my hunch is that you're suggestion is probably the preferred solution today. Feel free to edit my answer accordingly if you try it out and it works.

Comment: @Chase, I've just eye-balled ``scale_colour_manual(name = "", values =...`` versus ``guides(colour = guide_legend(title = NULL))`` in a clean example, and I can confirm the difference. The latter is therefore recommended over the former.

Comment: @Chase, there are a bunch of old ``ggplot`` questions out there with plenty of votes and google rank, but whose questions and answers refer to some deprecated code based on ``opts`` and the like. What is the recommended thing here, edit/update the questions and answers as I come across them or somehow flag them for some sort of "blacklisting" or inclusion of a warning or something (I don't know what the stackoverflow etiquette is).

Comment: @PatrickT - that's a very fair question, and one to which I don't think I have the answer to...probably something that the R community on here should think about and come up with a resolution...I often run into this same issue as I find my own answers from 3+ years ago when looking up how to do something now...it gets frustrating!

Comment: @Chase, thanks. I asked a meta (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281830/what-to-do-with-questions-answers-that-carry-obsolete-code)  Incidentally, I could NOT manage to update the code above, for some reason. Placing the ``stat="bin"`` or ``stat="identity"`` inside or outside the ``aes`` always seemed to yield an error message or not produce the bins shown by Andrie or rcs. I'm sure you know how to fix it and would be curious to know the correct syntax with the data provided by OP. Thanks!

Comment: @PatrickT - Thanks for asking that question, and the answers were also insightful. I updated the answer above to reflect what I *think* the intent of the answer was from a few years ago :). Let me know if you have any more questions. Cheers, - Chase

Comment: I had tried ``stat="identity"`` inside ``ggplot()``, in an ``aes()`` inside ``geom_bar()``, but had missed that (simpler) possibility! +1

Answer (score 1):

@pascal 's solution in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022898/how-can-i-remove-the-legend-title-in-ggplot2#comment41208703_6023078) to set the `name` argument of a scale function, such as `scale_fill_discrete`, to `NULL`, is the best option for me. It allows removing the title together with the blank space that would remain if you used `""`, while at the same time allowing the user to selectively remove titles, which is not possible with the `theme(legend.title = element_blank())` approach.

Since it is buried in a comment, I am posting it as an answer to potentially increase its visibility, with kudos to @pascal.

TL;DR (for the copy-pasters):

`scale_fill_discrete(name = NULL)`