# Remove legend title in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to remove the title of a legend in `ggplot2`:

```
df <- data.frame(
  g = rep(letters[1:2], 5),
  x = rnorm(10),
  y = rnorm(10)
)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, colour=g)) +
  geom_line(stat="identity") + 
  theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

[image]

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022898) and none of the solutions there seem to work for me. Most give an error about how `opts` is deprecated and to use `theme` instead. I've also tried various versions of `theme(legend.title=NULL)`, `theme(legend.title="")`, `theme(legend.title=element_blank)`, etc. Typical error messages are:

```
'opts' is deprecated. Use 'theme' instead. (Deprecated; last used in version 0.9.1)
'theme_blank' is deprecated. Use 'element_blank' instead. (Deprecated; last used in version 0.9.1)
```

I'm using `ggplot2` for the first time since version 0.9.3 was released and I'm finding it difficult to navigate some of the changes...

Comment: You can use `labs()` for this: Add the line `labs(colour = "")` to your code that produced the graph above.

Answer (score 274, accepted):

You were almost there : just add `theme(legend.title=element_blank())`

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, colour=g)) +
  geom_line(stat="identity") + 
  theme(legend.position="bottom") +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank())
```

[This page on Cookbook for R](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_%28ggplot2%29/) gives plenty of details on how to customize legends.

Comment: This will remove all legend titles. For more local control, the ``guide = guide_legend()`` command works. To remove the fill legend title, but to keep the color legend title, e.g. ``scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2", guide = guide_legend(title = NULL)) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("blue", "white", "red"))``

Answer (score 13):

This works too and also demonstrates how to change the legend title:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, colour=g)) +
  geom_line(stat="identity") + 
  theme(legend.position="bottom") +
  scale_color_discrete(name="")
```

Comment: This replaces the title with an empty string and therefore causes extra space between the label and the legend box, which would be visible only if the legend had a box or background of a color different from where it is positioned. So it's alright for a quick and ready approach in simple cases like ``theme_bw()`` but not the best in cases where the legend has a box around it and is positioned somewhere on the plot area (my usual approach).

Comment: +1 for the observation. i had the problem using two different legends and the whitespace between them that was created by the above solution. Setting `scale_color_manual(name=element_blank())+`for the lower legend solved it for me

Comment: @joaoal,  ``element_blank()`` seems to be the recommended approach. Setting ``name = NULL``  is another way.

Answer (score 5):

Another option using `labs` and setting colour to `NULL`.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, colour = g)) +
  geom_line(stat = "identity") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  labs(colour = NULL)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Since you may have more than one legends in a plot, a way to selectively remove just one of the titles without leaving an empty space is to set the `name` argument of the `scale_` function to `NULL`, i.e.

`scale_fill_discrete(name = NULL)`

(kudos to @pascal for [a comment on another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022898/how-can-i-remove-the-legend-title-in-ggplot2#comment41208703_6023078))

Answer (score 0):

For `Error: 'opts' is deprecated`. Use `theme()` instead. (Defunct; last used in version 0.9.1)'
I replaced `opts(title = "Boxplot - Candidate's Tweet Scores")` with
`labs(title = "Boxplot - Candidate's Tweet Scores")`. It worked!